# Microsoft Xbox API missing game clips

Tags: xbox, xbox-one

I'm implementing a service to get Xbox clips consuming directly Microsoft endpoints (I'm not using 3rd party APIs). I could successfully list some clips however some clips for specific games are missing (for example, FIFA and Halo). After investigation, I realized that Microsoft Xbox endpoints are not listing those clips, so is not a problem in my implementation. These are the 3 endpoints I'm checking:

- https://gameclipsmetadata.xboxlive.com/users/xuid()/clips?maxItems=25
- https://mediahub.xboxlive.com/dvr/gameclips
- https://avty.xboxlive.com/users/xuid()/activity/History?contentTypes=Game

None of them are listing FIFA clips or Halo clips. However, I checked other solutions like https://gamerdvr.com/ and they successfully list these clips.

So my question is, is there another endpoint that lists all the games properly? I'm missing some parameters in the request? Or maybe is there some configuration I should do in my account in order to get all the clips?